# how to debug a sub project inside a solution of visualstudio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a visualstudio solution with multipleprojects inside it.
How can i debug a project that is part of a solution, but one that does work independent of the main solution application. In short this 'side' project does do some automation required at installation time, but its not activated by the main program itself so hitting F5 wont do the trick for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the project in the solution explorer and select "Debug" > "Start New Instance".

Answer (score 3):

you can also set multiple startup project.

In Solution Explorer, select the solution.

On the Project menu, click Properties: the Solution Property Pages Dialog Box opens.

Expand the Common Properties node, and click Startup Project.

Click Multiple Startup Projects and set the project actions (e.g. Start or Start without debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, Go to Debug->Start new Instance